# Alternatives to whurl for sharing api responses

Tags: http, testing, rest

I used to use [whurl.heroku.com](http://whurl.heroku.com) to make http web requests and share the responses with people.  It's a great service for allowing people to see the results of requests themselves and test fixes.

It appears that whurl is going offline soon.  Are there any good alternatives out there (besides hosting my own)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems someone is hosting Whurl again on heroku.com, https://gcurl.heroku.com/.

Comment: That would be groupon (gcurl = groupon-curl). Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Mihai posted, I found [Advanced Rest Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo), a google chrome app.  I prefer ARC a little more as it's an app so it doesn't take up space in my URL bar, and also because it's easier to use and has a richer saved history feature than XHR.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XHR Poster](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/akdbimilobjkfhgamdhneckaifceicen) extension for Google Chrome. Contains many of the functionalities of whurl.

It has JSON pretty print feature and handles all types of requests.